# FastCGI исчезает FcgidIPCDir папка

Tags: linux, apache, fastcgi

В общем при установке fcgi указал я runtime папку в tmpfs чтоб оно диск не дергало.

```
FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm
```

Но боль в том, что эта папка убивается при перезагрузке а apache не может без нее запуститься, и создать видимо ее тоже не может. Можно как-то перед запуском сервиса апача создавать эту папку, ну или другие альтернативы, а то это мне качется костылём каким-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания папки при старте ОС используй [`tmpfiles.d`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html). Создай такой файл в `/etc/tmpfiles.d/fcgid.conf` :

```
 #Type Path                Mode UID      GID       Age Argument
 d     /var/run/mod_fcgid  0755 www-data www-data  -   -
```

Или, если "fcgid" запускается отдельным сервисом в systemd, найди его Юнит и добавь строчки:

```
RuntimeDirectory=/var/run/mod_fcgid 
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755
```

Можно добавить к юниту Апача, но тогда возможны проблемы при обновлении системы.